# Sveltekit provide a global variable to every +page.svelte

Tags: sveltekit

I have a project in which the page title is defined in a CMS. Now I want the title to be available to every page so that I can have the store name in every page title like "Home - MyPageTitle".

I don't want my CMS API to be publicly available so all the requests have to be made on the server.

Idealy the request to the CMS API shouldn't be executed on every page load. It should only be loaded when it's not set. Ideal would be a per session basis. I could add it to every +page.server.ts but there has to be a better way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a store for that. You can load the title in a [`+layout.server.js`/`ts` load function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data) and that passes the data to the layout/page. It then can be accessed as part of `data` in the layout or page.

Server-side caching depends on the [adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters) being used to build the application.